# Testing a parent class that children inherit from in Rspec.

Tags: rspec

I'm trying to test a parent class which future classes will inherit from. How do I do this simply in Rspec?

So far I have this:

```
let(:dummy_child_flow) do
    class ChildFlow < described_class
      operations TaxWorker, DiscountWorker
      transitions RefundFlow, CancellationFlow
    end

  end
  class TaxWorker; end
  class DiscountWorker; end
  class RefundFlow; end
  class CancellationFlow; end
end
```

The dummy_child_class is just a test child class that I'm creating that inherits from the `described_class`. The `described_class` has class methods called `operations` and `transitions` that take in other classes. I in short want to see that these class methods (located in the parent) are accessible to the child. This feels dirty. What's a better way to set this up?

Comment: This seems pretty convoluted.  I would move all this code to be part of the app instead of the specs. Then you can test `DummyChildFlow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to check is that the class methods are accessible to the child, you can check if the class responds to the particular method you want it to respond to.

```
class A
  def self.grin!
    ":D"
  end
end

class B < A; end

describe B do
  it "should have A's class methods"
    expect(described_class).to respond_to?(:grin!)
  end
end
```